# Convex quadratic maximization over cartesian product of simplices

Tags: quadratic-programming, nonconvex-programming, reformulation-linearization, relaxation

Suppose we are maximizing $f(x^1,\ldots,x^t)= \begin{bmatrix}{x^1}^\top & \ldots & {x^t}^\top  \end{bmatrix}^\top Q \begin{bmatrix}{x^1}^\top & \ldots & {x^t}^\top  \end{bmatrix}$ where $Q \succ 0$.

Let our constraints be $x^1, \ldots, x^t \in \mathcal{S}$ where $\mathcal{S}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a probability simplex.

Is there any rule-of-thumb for this problem? If we had only one simplex ($t = 1$) then we could enumerate the extreme points which is easy, but for the general case we have $n^t$ extreme points. I thought about the reformulation-linearization technique, but that would also result in a lot of constraints. Hence I was wondering if there is something easier.

Comment: Just to make it explicit, this is minimization of a concave objective subject to compact convex constraints, so there is a global optimum at an extreme point, which are the vertices. Why not just start out by trying a global optimization solver, such as BARON or Gurobi (which can globally optimize problems having quadratic objective and constraints), or CPLEX (which can globally  optimize QPs)? See how that goes before trying to develop some problem-specific method.

Comment: I am already using Gurobi nonconvex QP solver. I want to further understand how I can relax.

Comment: Let Gurob do it for you, automatically. Unless you're an expert at it, it's likely to do better than you. If you have to solve a lot of instances of the same problem, you could try the Gurobi tuner to give non-default solver parameter recommendations.